# Algo VPN vulnerabilities due to being hosted on cloud provider like Amazon

Tags: anonymity

I just set up Algo VPN on Amazon EC2. I'm wondering if this will be vulnerable to attacks if the Amazon EC2 instance is compromised. or if Amazon hand over my instance to someone else. Moreover the ISP in this case is Amazon, doesn't this give Amazon the ability to see my traffic? Also once a VPN is set up, the destination IP is static all the time. What do you think make Algo vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your questions because they are broad and all over the place.

Nonetheless:

> I just set up Algo VPN on Amazon EC2. I'm wondering if this will be
>   vulnerable to attacks if the Amazon EC2 instance is compromised.

If the EC2 instance itself is compromised, then you should assume that everything *on* it is compromised as well.

> or if Amazon hand over my instance to someone else.

I'm assuming you are referring to whether or not Amazon would hand over logs to a Law Enforcement Agency. It is very likely that they are legally compelled to do this in certain circumstances.

> What do you think make Algo vulnerable?

This is far too broad of a question.